# Python dataframe with value 'NA' not fetching

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a excel with below data:

[image]

But when i tried to debug the dataframe its showing only:

[image]

Could you explain why the NA is not showing in the dataframe.
Also is there any way to fetch NA .

Python version : 3.7

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: @Erfan print(pd.__version__) ->  0.25.1

Comment: If you read in your excel files, do you get empty cells or `NaN` everywhere? Because I get `NaN` for all the three rows.

Comment: @Erfan i am getting nan. Initially I removed all nan with empty sting using df.replace(np.nan,'',regex=True)

Comment: @Erfan where np is numpy

Comment: Did you try my answer? I tested it with the same excel file and it gives correct output

Comment: @Erfan Yes it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) there's an argument for this called `na_values`.

Quoted from the documentation:

> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN.

Furthermore you have to overwrite the default `NaN` values, which is also empty cell `''`, with the parameter `keep_default_na=False`

Again quoting from the documentation:

> If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to.

So the following should help your problem:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Filename.xlsx', na_values='NA', keep_default_na=False)
```

**Output**

```
     Item     Status
0    Soap        NaN
1  butter           
2    Rice        NaN
3     pen  Available
```

Comment: By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.

Comment: I don't understand this very well either